# Join one table with multiple tables in R

Tags: r, join, multiple-tables

I have around 800 data frames(a1,a2,a3...a800) in R and all of them have the same number of columns and column names.I want to a left join table a1 with rest of the 799 tables and store it in an object. Similarly, left join table a2 with the rest of them and store it another object and so on. I am unable to proceed with this! If anyone could help me will be great.

Here is an example
Table a1:
Names ID Time
X      1   2
Y      2   6
Z      3   5
K      4   8

Table a2;
Names ID Time
P     11   8
Q     12   9
R     10   7
Y      2   6
 and so on.. I want to join by ID Column. And I have 800 tables!

Comment: What do you mean by `join`. It is binding by rows that you mean?

Comment: do you mean rbind(a1, a2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: @Sonny By join I mean left join table a1 with rest of the 799 tables and have it stored in a separate object. Similarly a2 with the rest of the 799 tables and so on..

Comment: @NelsonGon I want a dynamic way to do it. Doing a j=left join on 1 table with 799 tables is task! I was hoping to get a simpler code!

Answer (score 0):

u can use `data.table::rbindlist`

```
dataframe_name_list = list(a1,a2,a3,...a800)
data.table::rbindlist(dataframe_name_list, use.names=TRUE)
```